# threejs pingpong approach for rendering to texture - no errors, nothing rendering to screen

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, webgl, feedback-loop

I'm trying to use the pingpong texture swap approach to create some smoke in threejs, following [this tutorial](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-write-a-smoke-shader--cms-25587) which dates back a few years. It uses an older version of threejs, and I can't seem to get it working with the most current version of the library.

There are no errors showing yet nothing is rendering to the screen... I wonder if anyone can help me see where I've gone wrong?

The code below was my own attempt at getting the first step of the tutorial to work - which involves the texture swap and a very simple shader that briefly fades from black to red. As I mentioned, everything works fine on an older version of library, [which you can see running here](https://codepen.io/elizasj/pen/ExegPez?editors=1010). I'd like to understand how to get it running properly on the most up to date iteration of threejs.

I found a clue from [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71567416/render-second-scene-to-texture-not-working) about how in the more up to date versions of threejs, `.render()` only accepts two arguments, which made me think that was the culprit of my error-less black screen, but even after reading through the docs some more, and adjusting my code, I still can't seem to get things working and have no errors to guide my searching.

the javascript:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import FragmentShader from './main.frag';

var scene;
var camera;
var renderer;

function scene_setup(){
    //This is the basic scene setup
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    //Note that we're using an orthographic camera here rather than a prespective
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( width / - 2, width / 2, height / 2, height / - 2, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 2;

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
}
//Initialize the Threejs scene
scene_setup();

  
var bufferScene;
var textureA;
var textureB;
var bufferMaterial;
var plane;
var bufferObject;
var finalMaterial;
var quad;

function buffer_texture_setup(){
    //Create buffer scene
    bufferScene = new THREE.Scene();
    //Create 2 buffer textures
    textureA = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter});
    textureB = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter} );

    //Pass textureA to shader
    bufferMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    uniforms: {
        bufferTexture: { type: "t", value: textureA },
        res : {type: 'v2',value:new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight)}//Keeps the resolution
    },
    fragmentShader: FragmentShader
    } );
    plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    bufferObject = new THREE.Mesh( plane, bufferMaterial );
    bufferScene.add(bufferObject);

    //Draw textureB to screen 
    finalMaterial =  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureB});
    quad = new THREE.Mesh( plane, finalMaterial );
    scene.add(quad);
}
buffer_texture_setup();


//Render everything!
function render() {

    requestAnimationFrame( render );

    //Draw to textureB
    // renderer.render(bufferScene,camera,textureB,true);
    renderer.setRenderTarget(textureB);
    renderer.clear();
    renderer.render(bufferScene,camera);
      
    //Swap textureA and B
    var t = textureA;
    textureA = textureB;
    textureB = t;
    quad.material.map = textureB;
    bufferMaterial.uniforms.bufferTexture.value = textureA;

    //Finally, draw to the screen
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
render();
```

the shader:

```
uniform vec2 res; //The width and height of our screen 
uniform sampler2D bufferTexture; //Our input texture 
void main() {
    vec2 pixel = gl_FragCoord.xy / res.xy;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D( bufferTexture, pixel );
    gl_FragColor.r += 0.01;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here, as I was able to find an answer in the threejs forums -- in fact I was really close! Just needed to correct the following:

textureB -> textureB.texture

textureA -> textureA.texture